# Issues with using Stack Overflow Search Filters for `answers` and `isaccepted` tags

Tags: support, questions

I am trying to search with the Stack Overflow search bar. And write in it:

```
flutter errors isaccepted:yes answers:1
```

I didn't get any results.

But I got a lot of results for:

```
flutter errors   answers:10
```

Or this:

```
flutter errors   isaccepted:yes
```

Is there a problem with the search or I don't know how to use it correctly?

Comment: Just to clarify, did you want to get a list of questions having more than 1 answer, and that answer is accepted?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As per the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching), `isaccepted` only returns **answers** that are accepted, while `answers` returns **questions** having N answers. Both are mutually exclusive, thus giving 0 results.

For questions having an accepted answer, **use `hasaccepted` instead.**

Example: [`flutter errors hasaccepted:yes answers:1`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=flutter+errors+hasaccepted%3Ayes+answers%3A1)

(note that `answers:1` in this case is redundant because it returns questions having 1 or more answers, while having an accepted answer also implies at least 1 answer. For questions having only 1 answer that is accepted, use `hasaccepted:yes answers:1..1`)